# How to acquire token in a native client to access a Web API that has been registered for Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization, azure-active-directory

I have a native client (console app) from where I am trying to access a WebAPI. The API has been authenticated using Azure AAD. So, in order to acquire a token using the method `AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken()`, ClientCredentials are needed which in turn need the "client secret" that one is supposed to receive from Azure while registering the application to Azure AAD. Is there any other way for me to be able to retrieve the access token to access the WebAPI?

Comment: Are you having issues with the ClientCredentials solution you described?  Just trying to understand the reason behind the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the WebAPI on behalf of (or "as") the current user then you can use the [Resource Owner Credentials flow](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/).  Otherwise, the client credential flow you described is the appropriate solution.

Note that your client app should be registered separately from your WebAPI in AAD.